# Pick up PHP resource using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, paging

I am setting up a paging with my web page. I have a `resource` containing a big result set, created as follows:

```
$sql = "select * from some_table";
pg_prepare($connection,"list",$sql);
$result = pg_execute($connection,"list",array());
$_SESSION['resultSet']=$result;
```

Theoretically, this would store the `resource` of the database result set in the `SESSION` and I could, using pointers, go select out the "next 25 rows" and then "the next 25 rows" using an ajax call.

Now, for some reason this `resource` stored in the session gets stored as a `integer` with the value of zero (in other words `false`).

So when I call this code (using AJAX):

```
$increment     = 25;
$array         = array();
$i             = 0;

while ($i<$amount) {
    $row = pg_fetch_array($_SESSION['resultSet'],null,PGSQL_ASSOC);
    array_push($array,$row);
    $i++;
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

I get an error saying that the `resource` fed into the `pg_fetch_array` function is an integer value.

Does anybody have any ideas how to properly implement such an idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Resources are only valid within the same PHP process that created it, they can't be saved in sessions.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't want to store the resultset in your session and pull pages from the session. This is why you have the database.

What you want to do is keep track of your pagination data in your javascript code (which initially it might come from PHP). Then when you fire ajax requests make sure that you are passing pagination data (current page number, number of results per page) to your server side script. Your server side script is then responsible for sending the correct LIMIT's to your DBMS (database server).

Comment: Thanks - I was hoping not to have to keep going back to the database, however I could implement `offset` in a query. My only question is if it would be smart to store it on the client side in a JSON object and then just keep going back to it. What is the standard?

Comment: You can store it in a JSON but you have to have a reason to do it. If you want to load the entire resultset in browsers memory and handle pagination this way without involving AJAX calls then you can do that. However, that isn't really a good idea when you have a large resultset! If you don't load it all at once, but load it page by page from a JSON file then that is pointless because you could have used a database instead.

Comment: Ok, last question: The only reason why I am avoiding calling from the DB every time is that the order of the result set COULD change with multiple updates hitting the table at any moment. Therefore, increment the `OFFSET` in a query and returning sequentially "the next 25", etc. could POSSIBLY result in retrieving the same record more than once (if the order changed). Is there some way to avoid this? If not, fine - but I am just asking